# Replacing every item at i with j value in an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Update here is a link of a working copy in a sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/3pkzc

So I am trying to run this code - trying to use the DOM to get index `.href` value and replace it.
But I am stuck at the last part of actually replacing the value `[j]` index with the value `[i]` index.
I've tried to push it on as it is an array and researched other methods but I am getting no where with this.

```js
// Get the URL of the big red button
const bigRedbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.bigRed');
//Convert into an array
const bigRedbtnArray = Array.from(bigRedbtn);
//Get all the links 
const bookTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.wp-show-posts-entry-title a');
console.log(bookTitles.length);
//Convert into an array
const bookTitlesArray = Array.from(bookTitles);
console.log(bookTitlesArray.length);

for (var i = 0; i < bigRedbtnArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < bookTitlesArray.length; j++) {

        //  what is the links for the book?
        const link = bigRedbtnArray[i].href;
        console.log(link);
        // console.log('bigRedbtn: ', bigRedbtn[i].href);

        //this is the title url to be replaced with the link from bigRedBtn
        const titleLink = bookTitlesArray[j].href;
        console.log(titleLink);

        //So can you do something like this

        //This is where I am stuck at
        //I need to replace each bookTitlesArray[j].href with the value of bigRedbtnArray[i].href

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your relevant HTML?  Please add a full working snippet of your problem.

Comment: Both `Array.from()` calls are unnecessary. You can access the elements in a `NodeList` like in an array (`bigRedbtn[0]`) or get the length of the list with `.length`. You could also use `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` to iterate over the elements in the list: `bigRedbtn.forEach((element, index) => { ... })`

Comment: Can you please add a [mcve] with an actual description of the requirement because I don't quite get the reason why there are two loops.

Comment: _“I need to replace each `bookTitlesArray[j].href` with the value of `bigRedbtnArray[i].href`”_ — what is the expected result? What is each `bookTitlesArray[j].href` supposed to look like in relation to each `bigRedbtnArray[i].href`? How does pushing onto an array help with replacing?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, Andreas, I did try to use forEach, but had to create two forEach func but then was stuck on the replace part. I know how to it like bigRedBtn[0].href = "www.bbc.co.uk" for example but this is just for the one I want to do it for all of the buttons. Thank you!

Comment: My comment is still relevant. Please add a [mcve] with the expected output and the actual requirement.

Comment: I will do building it now. Thanks!

Comment: All updated in the top of the question - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

S I asked on Reddit and this is the answer I got:

```
const bigRedbtn = document.querySelectorAll('a.bigRed');
const bookTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.wp-show-posts-entry-title');
bigRedbtn.forEach((n, i) => n.href = bookTitles[i].href)
```

Thanks to all who helped.